# Window Azure Deploying Cloud Services with A6 vmsize

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles

In my cloud service I have one web role and worker role. I changed my web role VM size from *medium* to *A6*.

When I tried to deploy to Windows Azure, I get the following error message:s seem prompt me error

> The VM size (or combination of VM sizes) required by this deployment cannot be provisioned due to deployment request constraints. If possible, try relaxing constraints such as virtual network bindings, deploying to a hosted service with no other deployment in it and  to a different affinity group or with no affinity group, or try deploying to a different region.

What does that mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically, you've asked it for one of the new "Uber" A6 Instances (with additional memory/process resources) and it was unable to provision your request (i.e. provide you with the required amount of cloud computing power for an A6 Instance).

You could try deploying to a different geographic location or affinity group or just wait and try again.

Comment: I tried to implement it on another cloud services. Its implemented successful. just take quite a long of time.