# Azure Cloud service cannot set vmsize to nothing other than: ExtraSmall, Small, Medium

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-cloud-services

I have had Azure Cloud service and I've tried to upgrade it to Standard D2 size, but upgrade failed, and I got same errors as in this question: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17422659/window-azure-deploying-cloud-services-with-a6-vmsize)

After that I created new Cloud Service in Azure portal and published my project with Standard D2 size, and that went well, but when I tried to integrate Continuous Deployment (with Git) it failed (I've tired my own Build Controller, and Hosted build Controller). After that I've tried with A5 instance size, but it failed too. The error I got both times was:

```
Exception Message: Invalid enum value 'A5' cannot be deserialized into type 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Deployment.Workflow.AzureManagement.v1_7.InstanceSize'. Ensure that the necessary enum values are present and are marked with EnumMemberAttribute attribute if the type has DataContractAttribute attribute. (type SerializationException)
```

Strangely I can publish my Cloud Service without problems, but I cannot use continuous deployment for some reason.

After that I removed Azure Cloud Service Project from my solution and added new Cloud Service Project, but with same results.

Then I tried to set instance size to "Large" and build went well.

And there is one more thing. In web role which is connected to ASP.net MVC project from drop down I can choose instances such as Standard D1, Satndard D2 etc. But from web role which is connected to ASP.net WEB Api project I can choose only Small, Large Medium, A5, etc. instances. (I've attached screenshots)

Why is this happening ?

Web API options: 
[image: Web Api]

MVC options:
[image: MVC]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've contacted Azure support, and this is answer I got:

We regret to inform you of a current system limitation that exists which restricts the ability to add a new D-Series to your current deployment which we are working to improve.  In order to use the new D-Series VM we are providing you with the steps to take to enable deployment:

- Delete the VM and retain your existing VHD
- Create a new D- Series VM in one of the following:

  - New Affinity Group
  - New Virtual Network
  - New Cloud Service

Individual clusters have different capabilities.  Not all cluster support all size VMs.  In general, the older ones support do not support the D series or A8/A9.  The A8/A9 clusters do not support the A1 thru A7 or D series.  Clusters that support A1 through A7 and the D series are newer clusters. Once you have completed the above steps you will be able to use the newly released D- Series VM in the new deployment created as depicted below.

[image]